# Is it possible to filter the sound from an embedded YouTube?

Tags: javascript, audio, youtube

Is it possible to somehow intercept the audio stream from a YouTube video and filter it? Specifically, I'd like to filter out the high and low frequencies and do some compression to make it sound like a megaphone.

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: Ok... so, next best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a javascript equalizer library, for example: http://www.wavesurfer.fm/example/equalizer/

Aside from actually equalizing, you'll need to get the audio. You may be able to utilize a service such as youtube-mp3 or you could strip the audio from the videos directly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to strip the audio from the videos directly. Do you happen to know if there's a way to do that?